# Problems with pygame.key

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame

I have a problem with this code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
def main():
    FPS=30
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300))
    RED=0
    GREEN=0
    BLUE=0
    LAST=None
    pygame.key.set_repeat(10,100)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_r:
                    print 'RED:',RED
                    RED = input('New value for RED: ')
                    print '='*10,'\n'
                    if RED>255:
                        RED=255
                    if RED<0:
                        RED=0
                    LAST='RED'
                if event.key==K_g:
                    print 'GREEN:',GREEN
                    GREEN = input('New value for GREEN: ')
                    print '='*10,'\n'
                    if GREEN>255:
                        RED=255
                    if GREEN<0:
                        GREEN=0
                    LAST='GREEN'
                if event.key==K_b:
                    print 'BLUE:',BLUE
                    BLUE = input('New value for BLUE: ')
                    print '='*10,'\n'
                    if BLUE>255:
                        BLUE=255
                    if BLUE<0:
                        BLUE=0
                    LAST='BLUE'
                if event.key==K_p:
                    print RED,GREEN,BLUE
                    print '='*10,'\n'
                if event.key==K_m:
                    if LAST=='RED':
                        RED+=1
                    if LAST=='GREEN':
                        GREEN+=1
                    if LAST=='BLUE':
                        BLUE+=1
                if event.key==K_l:
                    if LAST=='RED':
                        RED-=1
                    if LAST=='GREEN':
                        GREEN-=1
                    if LAST=='BLUE':
                        BLUE-=1
                if event.key==K_i:
                    print 'Last modified is:',LAST
                    print '='*10,'\n'
        DISPLAYSURF.fill((RED,GREEN,BLUE))
        pygame.display.flip()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
main()
```

It is just a stupid tool for me to play with colors (i know there are many online, but i wanted to write it by myself).
On my Mac everything goes right except for the part where the `event.key==K_m` is evaluated. It seems that this event is just ignored, when i press `m` nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: i'll try to reinstall python and pygame, i'll post what happens...

UPDATE: changed from `K_m` to `K_h`, everything works just fine. Then i have a problem with the `m` key on my keyboard or pygame does. I'll try some more, then just close this question if i can't find anything new.

BAD NEWS: reinstalled Python 2.7 32-bit (64 bit isn't compatible with pygame) and reinstalled pygame 1.9.1. Result: nothing changed. `K_m` isn't working anyway. I think there's a problem in my pc. Thanks to the ones who spent some time thinking of a solution, i hope i will be able to find a one...
Thanks again, and good work everyone!

Comment: all the other key events work?

Comment: Sure, every single one, that's what makes me fell there's something strange.

Comment: Hey, u shouldn't put the answer inside the question. Post a new answer instead.

Comment: but this way it's faster, cause someone having this problem will immediately find the answer... isn't that right?

Comment: If your issue is solved, mark an answer as accepted instead of editing the title. If you found the solution yourself, you can post an answer and accept that if you feel that no other answer solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This evening i tried to use this code

```
import pygame, sys, os
import numpy as np
from pygame.locals import *

FPS=30
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
RED   = (255,  0,  0)
GREEN = (  0,255,  0)
BLUE  = (  0,  0,255)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==KEYDOWN or event.type==KEYUP:
                print event
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_g:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_r:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(RED)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_b:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLUE)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_m:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.flip()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

main()
```

the m key not working etc...
Pressing m would just return

```
<Event(2-KeyDown {'scancode': 46, 'key': 44, 'unicode': u'm', 'mod': 0})>
<Event(3-KeyUp {'scancode': 46, 'key': 44, 'mod': 0})>
```

but did not change anything.
God wnows why i decided to change `event.key==K_m` to `event.unicode==u'm'` and the code WORKED! I was really surprised, and i changed `event.unicode==u'm'` to `event.key==44` and it WORKED!
I don't really understand why this way it works, but it works and that's all that matters to me. I hope this solution may help other people with similar kind of errors!
I'm now using the event.unicode everywhere, it's easier than finding the key number of each character.

**WORKING CODE**

```
import pygame, sys, os
import numpy as np
from pygame.locals import *

FPS=30
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
RED   = (255,  0,  0)
GREEN = (  0,255,  0)
BLUE  = (  0,  0,255)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==KEYDOWN or event.type==KEYUP:
                print event
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_g:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_r:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(RED)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_b:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLUE)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.unicode==u'm':
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.flip()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

main()
```

or

```
import pygame, sys, os
import numpy as np
from pygame.locals import *

FPS=30
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
RED   = (255,  0,  0)
GREEN = (  0,255,  0)
BLUE  = (  0,  0,255)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==KEYDOWN or event.type==KEYUP:
                print event
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_g:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_r:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(RED)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_b:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLUE)
            if event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==44:
                DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.flip()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

main()
```